Weird behaviour of type inference when using "if" statement with object property
Can you take a look at this code. Why Typescript is complaining about the code inside the first "if" statement, and not complaining about the code in the second one?
export type IssueProps = {
    type: 'job_warning' | 'job_error' | 'task_warning'
    jobId?: string
}

export type JobIssueProps = IssueProps & {
    type: 'job_warning' | 'job_error'
    jobId: string
}

const sendDeadlineJobErrorAlert = (
        deadlineIssue: JobIssueProps,
    ) => {
        console.log(deadlineIssue)
    }

const issue = {} as IssueProps

if (issue.type === 'job_error' && issue.jobId) {
    // typescript reports an error
    sendDeadlineJobErrorAlert(issue)
}

if (issue.type === 'job_error' && issue.jobId) {
    // typescript doesn't report an error
    sendDeadlineJobErrorAlert({...issue, type: issue.type, jobId: issue.jobId})
}

Playground Link
This is the typescript error
Argument of type 'IssueProps' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JobIssueProps'.
  Type 'IssueProps' is not assignable to type '{ type: "job_warning" | "job_error"; jobId: string; }'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type '"job_warning" | "job_error" | "task_warning"' is not assignable to type '"job_warning" | "job_error"'.
        Type '"task_warning"' is not assignable to type '"job_warning" | "job_error"'.

Is this a flaw of Typescript that it cannot narrow down the type correctly, or am I doing something wrong?

It's a missing feature of TS, see ms/TS#42384 and the linked q/a above.
